# Automating cell references

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, split, transpose, flatten

I have a standard sheet formatted like this, with columns going linearly

First Name  Last Name   Contact Type    Address Address 2   City    State

My goal is to take the data in this sheet and format it differently in another sheet, like this, vertically

First Name Last Name

Contact Type

Address

Address 2

City State Zip

For the users, they can then use this to print out mailing labels (plus for some of my users, reading info in block form is just easier)

So I can do something like this in the new sheet

={NameDirectory!B4&" "&NameDirectory!C4}

={NameDirectory!D4}

={NameDirectory!E4&" "&NameDirectory!F4}

etc, so each line grabs the right data, so the address appears in a block

Of course, the next block will be similar

={NameDirectory!B5&" "&NameDirectory!C5}

={NameDirectory!D5}

={NameDirectory!E5&" "&NameDirectory!F5}

The only thing that changes is the number as I have merely shifted down a row.

I keep thinking there must be an easier way to do this, other than copying the formula, pasting it in and manually changing B5 to E5. Likewise, I can drag the formula down multiple rows, but it changes the number not the letter as I want.

Is there anyway I can achieve what I want without a lot of copying and pasting?

Here is an example (not sharing the original as it as real contact information, so this has two entries, but the original has around 50+)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ob4JXRT0CqqOb94-3Mqt1wu2LSsm3oeodc0eTPtT_3U/edit#gid=0

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Added a link to an example (not the original but an example of what I want to do)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: sorry, made it public https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ob4JXRT0CqqOb94-3Mqt1wu2LSsm3oeodc0eTPtT_3U/edit#gid=0

Comment: If you drag-copy, cell references change automatucally. To fix column or line to be constant they should have $ before them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 {Sheet1!A2:A&" "&Sheet1!B2:B, Sheet1!C2:E, Sheet1!F2:F&", "&Sheet1!G2:G&" "&Sheet1!H2:H, Sheet1!I2:K, 
 IF(Sheet1!A2:A="",," ")}, " ", CHAR(13))),,9^9)), " "), "where not Col2 contains ','", 0)))
```

[image]